# How to create a row entry in an Access database using VB.Net that begins with an Autonumber?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, vba

I’m trying to create an ATM solution in VB.net that corrects their balance when withdrawl is clicked and also creates a row in transaction history database. It currently writes to the transaction history database but only appears when I delete the first column “TransNo”. However without transaction number there it crashes. Outlined below is my Access database and VB.net public function to write the row entry. I believe that I need to add a line above “dateoftrans” that writes the auto number also but I haven’t been able to find any solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Nzc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvsx5.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, take note. Do not post images of your code. Code is made of text and as text we could copy and test it. Images are useless for code. Also the table structure could be easily written in text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does any insert work for you?

And “crashes” is poor wording. What is the error message you  get?

This code works fine for me:

```
    Dim MyReader As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from tblHotels2", _
                                               "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Test2\test44.accdb")

    Dim cmdUpate As New OleDbCommandBuilder(MyReader)

    Dim rst As New DataTable()
    MyReader.Fill(rst)
    With rst.Rows.Add()
        .Item("HotelName") = "My Company"
    End With

    MyReader.Update(rst)
```